# Passing index value from select to inside php block in one page html

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5

I have two select dropdown. Example:If i select index 3 in the first
 select option,the display of the 2nd select option should stop at
 index 3.What is the best way of doing it.See my current code below.

```
<label class="control-label">SY1:</label> 
<select class="form-control" name="pri_sy" id="pri_sy" onchange="">
<?php 
    $null = 'Null';
    $choose = 'Choose School Year';
    $Present = 'Present';
    echo '<option value='.$null.'>' .$choose.'</option>';
    echo '<option value='.$Present.'>' .$Present.'</option>';
    for($i=date('Y');  $i > date('Y')-27; $i--){
        $x = $i +1;
        $y = $i;
        echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.'>'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
    }?>
</select>

Result: 
[0]Choose School Year
[1] Present
[2] 2017-2018
[3] 2016-2017   if selected index[3] / How can i pass 3 in my 2nd for loop?
   2015-2016   for($i=date('Y');  $i > date('Y')-3; $i--)/See below php code..
[5]2014-2015
[6]2013-2014
and so on ...



<label class="control-label">SY2:</label> 
    <select class="form-control" name="sec_sy" id="sec_sy" onchange="">
    <?php 
        $null = 'Null';
        $choose = 'Choose School Year';
        $Present = 'Present';
        echo '<option value='.$null.'>' .$choose.'</option>';
        echo '<option value='.$Present.'>' .$Present.'</option>';
        for($i=date('Y');  $i > date('Y')-3; $i--){
            $x = $i +1;
            $y = $i;
            echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.'>'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
        }?>
    </select>

Expected Result:
Choose School Year
Present
2017-2018
2016-2017    
2015-2016



<script type="text/javascript">

$('.form-control').on('change', function(e) {
  var pri_sy = $("#pri_sy").find("option:selected").index();
  var sec_sy   = $("#sec_sy").find("option:selected").index();
  var sen_high_sy = $("#sen_high_sy").find("option:selected").index();
  var college_sy = $("#college_sy").find("option:selected").index();

  var isPri = $(this).is("#pri_sy");
  var isSec = $(this).is("#sec_sy");
  var isSenHigh = $(this).is("#sen_high_sy");
  var isCollege = $(this).is("#college_sy");
  //console.log("from:"+fromIdx,"to:"+toIdx);
  if (isPri) {
    alert('a');
    $('#sec_sy').val(pri_sy);
    alert(pri_sy);
       // $('#sec_sy').each(function(pri_sy, sec_sy) {     
      // $(sec_sy).attr('disabled', pri_sy < sec_sy);
     });
  }  
}).change();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page load, extract the options from the second select and clear the second select. Then when an index is selected, compute the options from your extraction (here the X first options) and then insert them in the second select.

**EDIT:**

Either you have the two select with all the options. Then in Javascript you get the options from the second and clear it. Then when the first select change, you insert the good values in the second.

Or you use an input hidden with a text containing the values for the second select (ex 'value1;value2'). Then you get the value in javascript and split it (here on the ':'). Then you update the second select when the first change.

Comment: Sir,Where to put the computation,inside the php block?

Comment: In your Javascript. You can either let the 2 select with all options and change the second in function of the first. Or use input hidden with a string containing all the values of the second select that you should parse.